# mailto hyperlink with percent encoding doesn't save in powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint, urlencode, mailto

I have an percent-encoded email address that I'd like to link from Powerpoint 2016. After creating and checking the link, it works, but as soon as I close the document and reopen it, the link doesn't work correctly because the encoding has been omitted.

Here is my example:

- The actual address: **R&DValidationSupport@aruplab.com**
- The encoded address and what is entered into the E-mail address field:
  **mailto:R%26DValidationSupport%40aruplab.com**
- The link that exists after I reopen the document (after saving): **mailto:R&DValidationsupport@aruplab.com** And of course, when clicked, only the "R" appears.

Any tips on making this a clickable link--with the right address?

Thanks!

Comment: If this email address is one at your company, you could possibly set up an alias like RandDValidationSupport@aruplab.com that autoforwards to the correct address. If you eliminate the ampersand, you can type the actual email address into the hyperlink field, no need to encode the @ symbol, and it works.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks for this workaround option. I'll see if our IT group will accommodate the request. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, another approach:

If you "percent encode" the percent sign as well, the link will work after you've saved and reopened the presentation:

mailto:R%2526DValidationSupport@aruplab.com

BUT (or perhaps we should spell that BUG?):

If you then save and re-open the presentation again, the link will have turned into

mailto:R%26DValidationSupport@aruplab.com

and will no longer work.